# For any of the $16$ subsets with cardinality $3$ of $\mathbb Z_7$, show there always exists $2$ sets s.t. the sum of elements are equal.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Problem: For any of the $16$ subsets with cardinality $3$ of $\mathbb Z_7$, show that there always exists two sets, so that if you sum the elements of one set, it is the same as the other. For instance, $\sum ${$1,2,3$}=$\sum ${$5,1,0$}.

My solution: I first set bounds on $\sum X$, where $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z_7$. Well, we know that the minimal sum is $0+1+2=3$, so $3\leq \sum X$. And we also know that the maximum value of this sum is $4+5+6=15$, so we have the bounds $3\leq \sum X \leq 15$. Thus $\sum X$ can take at most $12$ different values. Let $A$ be the set of all possible values of the $12$ digit sums of $X$. Similarly, denote $B$ as the set of all possible values of the $12$ digit sums of $Y$. We then have that the problem reduces to the following statement: $A \cap B \neq 0$.

Assume that $A \cap B =0$. Then if we denote $C$ as the set of all possible sums of all possible subsets of $\mathbb Z_7$, we have that $|C|=12$. Also note that by the inclusion-exclusion principle, $|A \cup B|$=$|A|+|B| -$$|A \cap B|$=$24$. But then notice that $|A \cup B|$=$|C|$=$12$. A contradiction.

After this, one can make the more general statement that this could work for any two sets, for any value of the sums of those sets, and be far more general.

I would like to know whether my solution is correct and that if one could try and apply the pigeonhole principle to this problem.

Comment: "*First, I set bounds on $\sum X$*"  Uh... Minimum value of $3$?  But $1+2+4=0$ in this context I thought?  There are just seven possible sums, $0,1,2,\dots,6$.  We could have gotten away with there being just eight such sets.

Comment: OOPS! I was lazy, and wanted to just use $\mathbb Z_7$ instead of {$0,1,2,3,4,5,6$}! My bad!

Comment: You can use $[7]$ to represent $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,6\}$ instead.  Note that some authors prefer this to be $\{1,2,3,\dots,7\}$ so you do have to occasionally clarify if it matters.  Most times though it doesn't matter at all as it is just meant to be "the quintessential set with seven elements" and the results being talked about are the same regardless which was intended.  For example the number of functions from $[n]$ to $[m]$ is $m^n$

Comment: So then, we have some number of three-element subsets of $[7]$ and are wanting to show that at least two of these have the same sum, whatever that might be.  You correctly found then that $0+1+2=3$ is smallest and $4+5+6=15$ is largest, giving a range of $13$ possible sums (*don't forget the first and last in your count*).  We have more than $13$ subsets to look at and compare, so we are done by the pigeonhole principle by letting the sets be the pigeons and the possible sums be the holes.  No additional explanation needed.

Comment: There are $13$ different integer values $S$, not just $12$, satisfying $3 \leq S \leq 15$. And where did $Y$ come from?

Comment: Thank you! So $ceil(16/13)=2$, where $16$ is the number of sets, and $13$ is the number of possible sums. Correct?

Comment: $Y$ is a set like $X$. A set so that $|X|$=$|Y|$=$3$

Comment: Where does 16 come from?  $\binom{7}{3}=35$.

Comment: @RobPratt The question was poorly worded, yes.  My interpretation is "*Supposing we were given $16$ arbitrary subsets of size three of $\{0,1,2,\dots,6\}$, show that...*"  That there are more unused subsets is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

For any $3$-element subset of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, you correctly note that its sum is at least $0+1+2=3$ and at most $4+5+6=15$. This leaves at most $13$ possible values for the sum of such a $3$-element subset. Hence $16$ such subsets cannot all have distinct sums, meaning that there are at least $2$ subsets with the same sum.